# Kirki: generate toggles for each taxonomy term

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm using Kirki and trying to generate a toggle for each term in custom taxonomy (to add ability to show/hide posts for each term in the theme later):

```
function generate_toggles() {
$months = get_terms( array('months') );
    foreach ($months as $month) :
        Kirki::add_field( 'mytheme', array(
            'type'        => 'toggle',
            'settings'    => $month->slug,
            'label'       => __( 'Июль', 'my_textdomain' ),
            'section'     => 'months',
            'default'     => '1',
            'priority'    => 10,
        ));
    endforeach;
}
add_action('???', 'generate_toggles', 9999);
```

What I don't understand though is where do I attach the action? Since I want it in Kirki panel – which action should I attach it to?

Comment: You don't need an action. Or a wrapping function... you can just write your `foreach` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Kirki helper class for this (pass your taxonomy into **Kirki_Helper::get_terms**), but you need to register after the taxonomies are registered, otherwise you get an error:

```
function my_theme_add_categories_customizer_control() {
Kirki::add_field('my_config', array(
    'type' => 'multicheck',
    'settings' => 'show_months',
    'label' => esc_attr__('My Control', 'my_textdomain'),
    'section' => 'months',
    'priority' => 10,
    'choices' => Kirki_Helper::get_terms(array('months'))
));
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_add_categories_customizer_control', 12 );
```